# Android application to detect when Google maps direction is finished

Tags: android, google-maps

I am building an android application, that will show certain points on google maps, for which I have (lat,lang) for all the points shown, with me. Whenever, a user clicks on one of these locations on google maps, I am starting a new Google Maps intent which shows navigation to the user and is supposed to take the user to that (lat, lang).

```
//suppose this function is called on onclick of google maps event
    function onclick(){
            Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("google.navigation:q=32.885240,-96.763475");
            Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri);
            mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
            if (mapIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                startActivity(mapIntent);
            }
    }
```

This will start the navigation for the user. Now what I want to achieve is this - Whenever this navigation is complete, I want some kind of flag to be passed to my android application, so that my application knows that the navigation has been finished.

If it is possible to automatically close the google maps application after the navigation has been completed, it will be nice to have.

Comment: the google maps app does not return anything when the route has finished

Comment: I think the best you could do would be use `startActivityForResult(mapIntent, num)` and then detect when `onActivityResult()` is called with requestCode of num, this might work to detect if the user clicks back to go back to your app.

Comment: So to confirm my understanding of your answer, this will detect only if the user clicks back to my app, Right? Not when the Google Maps intent has finished navigation. If someone clicks back on my app during the navigation, it will detect that as well which is not what I want. But, thanks, this information may come in handy somewhere else. I did not know this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Daniel mentioned, you can use `onActivityResult()` to detect when users are back. However, if you really want to detect if Google maps direction had finished... You can look at the notifications.

So the catch here is, when Google Maps direction is a services, and when it is running, it posts updates to the notifications center.

Which means either you can keep looking at what services are running, or.. get permission to the notifications center and keep checking if Google Maps exists.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this approach may work for me. Let me try to implement this.However, if I find some difficulty in implementing this, I will post a comment here asking for more help.

Comment: @NalinAgrawal Did you try this? Please provide feedback if you did. Thanks!

Comment: No I did not. I stopped developing the project. However, I would only go to this solution if nothing else works. Because this means constant polling, every second which is going to take a lot of cpu cycles and battery consumption. Plus it is dependent on a feature provided by maps. Not by their APIs.

Answer (score 0):

I think a better answer since you built the intent for navigation and have the coordinates, is to set up geofencing for the destination or any milestone you want in the trip. After that, you can use your IntentService to retrieve your app at the appropriate activity.

https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing#java

Comment: That's what I did.