# How to return from Google Maps App to my app?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, google-maps-api-2

From my app I'm calling Google Maps app using Intent and everything works well.

My question is:

how do I get back from Google Maps app to my app?

If I use the device "back" button then I need to press it 4-5 times!
Does anybody have a better solution?

Comment: why are youe calling google maps app, include a mapfragment in your activity and send data beetwen the same app

Comment: Can you please further explain?

Comment: you can include google maps in your app you can read oficial documentation https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start and use whatever you want in your app.

Comment: Here is a simple example https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/index?hl=es

Comment: Already did that and everything is working.

Comment: But I want to navigate from A to B, and I understand that I can only achive that if I use Google Maps app - And since I have to use another app I still need to get my question answered. How do I return to my app from another app (Google Maps in specific)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android does not give you control to the activities you launch. And since it mentioned nothing in the [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/intents), it possibility means you can not.

One thing might help is it seems your application can check whether if the navigation is currently running. Look at this post for more information on that: [Android application to detect when Google maps direction is finished](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31462994/android-application-to-detect-when-google-maps-direction-is-finished/31466071#31466071)

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to create an AlarmManager right before you start the Maps Activity, save any variables in sharedPreferences and then let the Map Intent do what it has to do. After x time has passed(You decide how much time needs to pass before returning to your app) in the BroadcastReceiver open up your app in the activity that you want. Then load any needed variables that you stored in the sharedPreferences and done!
In essence it works like an alarm clock, you set the time and after x time you notify the user. I followed this tutorial(I used only the part I needed):

http://stacktips.com/tutorials/android/repeat-alarm-example-in-android